# MonteCarlo Power Analysis: 3 -Level MSEM in MPLUS

Tags: statistics, montecarlo

I am running a MonteCarlo simulation for a 3-level 1-1-2 MSEM in MPLUS and I keep getting the following error code:

*** ERROR in MONTECARLO command
The total number of observations in the CSIZES option does not
match the number of observations specified in NOBSERVATIONS.

But the numbers in the Nobservations and Csizes are the same? So, I don't really know what to do.

Below is the code bit that I'm using. The data are a 3-level EMA study with 289 participants, 14 days for each person, and 5 assessments within each day.

```
MONTECARLO:                                     
NAMES ARE x m y;                                
NOBS = 20230;                            
NCSIZES = 1[1];                                 
CSIZES = 289(14[5]);                       
SEED = 347;                                     
NREPS = 1000;
```